# In the context of progress monitoring and updating a progress bar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

In the context of progress monitoring and updating a progress bar. One could start a timer and update the progress bar every i.e. couple of seconds. We measure the time it takes to complete the task and hard code the number of seconds it takes. And it kinda works, unless i.e. the time task takes to complete is not constant. Also, if the implementation of the task change, becoming slower/faster, then task might complete when task bar is on i.e. 10% which wont look great.

If time is not constant there is another approach. Let's say to `doSomething` we cross over a couple of waypoints in which we emit a signal to report the progress.
We pass in the total number of waypoints (i.e. 3) and on every waypoint we compute the ratio.

However if we add/remove waypoints we have to adjust the call, instead of `doSomething(3)` it might be i.e. `doSomething(5)`. Unless we find a way to update that `int total = 3` at compile time automatically, would that be possible? Perhaps preprocessor macros? Can I count the number of times I call `process()` at compile time?

widget.h

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Task m_task;

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    {
        connect(&m_task, &Task::status, this, &Widget::showProgrss);
    
        int total = 3;
        m_task.doSomething(total);
    }

public slots:
    void showProgrss(float p)
    {
        qDebug() << " - progress" << p;
    }
};
```

task.h

```
class Task : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    float m_total= 0;
    int count = 0;

public:
    explicit Task(QObject *parent = nullptr){}

    void doSomething(int t)
    {
        m_total = t;
        progress();
        func1();
        progress();
        func2();
        progress();
    }

private:
    void progress()
    {
        float p = (++count/m_total)*100;
        emit status(p);
    }

    void func1()
    {
//        progress();
    }

    void func2()
    {
//        progress();
    }

signals:
    void status(float p);
};
```

With the above, output was:

```
 - progress 33.3333
 - progress 66.6667
 - progress 100
```

But if we uncomment one of those calls to `progress()`, it outputs:

```
 - progress 33.3333
 - progress 66.6667
 - progress 100
 - progress 133.333
```

Which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Your question seems kind of open-ended. What is it exactly that you want us to answer? It sounds like your question is: "What is the best way to calculate progress?" People may offer different ideas, but is there a factually correct way?

Comment: Oh, it's not that. Is it possible to count, at compile time, the number of times a function (`progress()`) is called? And then automatically update `int total = 3;`?

Comment: A good practice is to define progress in terms of some quantity inherent to the domain problem. Example: bytes transferred compared to file size. If it can only be measured by a number of actions taken, perhaps define an enum class describing the specific action types, and force each caller to identify the action just taken. That makes it harder to screw it up, and less severe degradation if you do.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to change your approach. Don't try to count function calls. Instead, structure your progress steps in a way that the total is implicitly counted for you. Like storing them in a vector.

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> m_steps {
    step1,
    step2,
    step3
}

void doSomething() 
{
    for (auto &f : m_steps) {
        f();
        progress();
    }
}

void progress()
{
    float p = (++count/m_steps.size())*100;
    emit status(p);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. However this might led to some serious refactoring because code here is spread across a coupe  of classes.

Comment: I like the inclusion of functions (lambdas) explicitly in data structures as part of a problem solution model. And that step execution is so tightly coupled with the progress calculations.